# Using divs that scales to 100% height and doesn't fills up with background color with resized window

Tags: html, css

i have problem with my project. I have web page with 3 columns.  Using divs that scales to 100% height. It works when i load page in full screen, my three columns scales to 100% (filled with background color) but problem appears when the page is resized to small window, all the content in the middle column shrinks and the scroll bar appears to view  the rest of the content  but then my all divs do not fill up with the background color. Color fills up only to the view port dimensions what 100% hight is supposed to do. How could i get the result that would allow me to fill the divs with the bg color not only to the existing view port  dimensions but to the rest of the  document. Here's a link to my project

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dudalykai/8u50Lphy/2/

Answer (score 0):

Set page height to 100%.

```
.parent {
    height: 100%
}
```

Also, if you are using floats you would need to clear after them like this:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: Oops, I meant the parent class.

Comment: Doesn't help, it extends only divs with this class to 100% visible screen size and thats it. My goal is to extend divs to 100% html document size.  I can see that in a small resized  window my divs are not filled with color its because I use 100% height which means 100% of visible screen size.